# ListView not working properly after calling Sort()-Function

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, listview, listviewitem

I am currently working on this old, rusted .NET Framework Platform.

In my form I have a ListView, and I´m adding some data-tagged items into it.
The new data-tagged item gets placed one step under the selected one, when one is selected.

I press on one columnheader, which forces the listview to sort the items alphabetically.
I again add a data-tagged item into it.
The ListView places it at index 0, although I have selected an item?
Pls see the video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pdAjHzylVCZjDzR3QltF_1v371hAb_3r/view?usp=sharing

Why in the hell is this so?
Any suggestion of why this problem is accouring?

Thanks for your attention!

Here´s the Code:
--when adding a data-tagged item--

```
        private void btnAddSecuring_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            
            int insertIndex = viewSecurings.SelectedItems.Count >= 1 ? viewSecurings.SelectedIndices[0] + 1 : 0;
            Securing sec = new Securing(viewSecurings);
            ListViewItem item = viewSecurings.Items.Insert(insertIndex, new ListViewItem() { Tag = sec } );
            sec.ShowInListViewItem(item);
            item.Selected = true;
            item.BeginEdit();


        }

    // in Securing.cs:
    public void ShowInListViewItem(ListViewItem item)
    {
        while (item.SubItems.Count < 3)
        {
            item.SubItems.Add("");
        }

        item.SubItems[0].Text = name;
        item.SubItems[1].Text = lastExecuteToStr();
        item.SubItems[2].Text = getTotalSrcBytes().ToString();
    }
```

--when clicking on columnheader--

```
        private void viewSecurings_ColumnClick(object sender, ColumnClickEventArgs e)
        {
            currentColumnIndex = e.Column;
            SortSecurings();
        }

        void SortSecurings()
        {
            
            viewSecurings.ListViewItemSorter = new ListViewItemComparer(currentColumnIndex);
            viewSecurings.Sort();
        }
```

The program gets solved when I´m not changing the text of the new added item:
That means removing "item.SubItems[0].Text = name" solves the problem.
But why?

-- code of ListViewItemComparer --
http://csharp-slackers.blogspot.com/2008/09/how-to-sort-list-view-by-any-column.html

Comment: Guys I could fix it by myself one, two minutes and I will post my solution!

Answer (score 1):

the trick was to set the ListViewItemSorter-property to null, after using it:
In the constructor:

```
private ListViewColumnSorter lvwColumnSorter;
public ControlSecurings()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lvwColumnSorter = new ListViewColumnSorter();
        SortSecurings();
    }
```

New "SortSecurings()" Method:

```
void SortSecurings()
    {
        viewSecurings.ListViewItemSorter = lvwColumnSorter; // <-- important!
        this.viewSecurings.Sort();
        viewSecurings.ListViewItemSorter = null; // <-- important!
    }
```

I'm using antoher sorter now, but that shouldn't change the principle.
Wish you a nice day!